# cakephp - disabling ACL in non admin action

Tags: cakephp, acl

I'm quit a noobie in cake.
I've encountered bad performance issues when site is uploaded, although using cash mechanism.
I suspect the ACL mechanism is to blame with the bad performance.
Since I dont need different actions per user, I'd rather disable this for the non admin functionality, but enable it for admin.
Can it be done?
Please advise.
Thanks
Orly

Answer (score 0):

You dont need ACL for that! I suggest you remove ACL and use Auth component.

Use Auth component and Admin prefix for the admin section.